# How do I create an Automator Application to forward new mail from Mac Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, automator

I have an old e-mail address linked to my Mac Mail account.  I have made a rule that forwards new mail from a specified address - call it `johndoe@test.com` - between my old e-mail and my current e-mail.  Right now, I need to manually open the Mail application for the rule to apply to new mail.

I'd like to do this automatically, without needing to manually open and close Mac Mail.  To avoid opening it manually, I created an Automator program that performs the following actions on a daily basis:

[image: My Mac Mail Automator script]

While this Automator Application opens and quits Mac Mail, it doesn't seem to work, as my current address doesn't receive any forwarded e-mails.  Is there another way to automatically forward e-mails from `johndoe@test.com` from my old e-mail address (linked to Mac Mail) to my new one?

Comment: why does not the mail rule works for you? but show us your Automator to see where the problem is!

Comment: Automator does not have forwarding for Apple Mail, only for Outlook. Is your AOL a account in Apple Mail?

Comment: The Mail rule works when I manually open Mac Mail.  When I attempt to use my Automator script, mail is neither collected nor forwarded.  Thanks for the feedback; I attached a screenshot!

Comment: My AOL account is separate.  I have Outlook as well but haven't tried that yet.  It wasn't obvious from the Outlook's Automator commands how I would properly forward new e-mails.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear :( how do you access AOL mail? true website, true Apple mail, true outlook? If you make it a part of apple mail (as a account) then forwarding rule should work for you.

Comment: It is not really clear what your setup is or what you really are expecting. Automator will NOT be able to just run a forward when a new email arrives, unless Mail.app is open and it has a Mail rule that runs the Automator workflow.

Comment: I access AOL mail through both Apple Mail and website.  The AOL mail is part of Apple Mail as an account, but that forwarding rule isn't working. @markhunte perhaps it is because of what you suggested - that Automator will not work in the way I hope because I need to open it and have a mail rule that applies the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your new email service? Perhaps you can configure it to check your AOL mailbox and pull it down.  This would happen automatically on their servers and wouldn't require a script on your side.

For example, if your new email service was with Gmail, go into the Settings>Accounts tab and add your AOL account to the "Check mail from other accounts" section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  My new service is GMail, but But the reason I decided to not do this approach is because I only want a small subset of the e-mails from my old account - namely, those from a particular sender.

Comment: Could you set up a filter on the AOL mail system to trash ever email except those from this particular sender?  Then you can set up Gmail to fetch the AOL emails and all that is left would be those that you want.

Comment: Hm, it's not the most straightforward solution, but it'll work!